# Java arrays how to save it in the array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I save it actually in the Array?
With this code it doesn't save anything in the array
I hope you can tell me more ways how to do it and explain in detail, thank you very much

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountArray
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int countPOZ = 0;
        int countP5 = 0;
        int countNONE = 0;

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Type elements: ");
        int[] x = new int [scan.nextInt()];

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Type numbers: ");
            int numrat = scan.nextInt();

            if(numrat > 0)
                countPOZ++;
            else if (numrat % 5 == 0)
                countP5++;
            else
                countNONE++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(x[1]); //here it will display 0 because nothing is saved.. in the array
        System.out.println("Positive: "+countPOZ);
        System.out.println("Div.. with 5: "+countP5);
        System.out.println("Others: "+countNONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You store a value in the `i`th position of your `x` array with:

```
x[i] = someValue;
```

In the context of your loop :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Type numbers: ");
        int numrat = scan.nextInt();

        if(numrat > 0)
            countPOZ++;
        else if (numrat % 5 == 0)
            countP5++;
        else
            countNONE++;
        x[i] = numrat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This stores the user's input in order.

```
x[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the local `numrat` and use `x[i]`. And please use braces, something like

```
x[i] = scan.nextInt();
if(x[i] > 0) {
    countPOZ++;
} else if (x[i] % 5 == 0) {
    countP5++;
} else {
    countNONE++;
}
```

This is covered in and an example to [JLS-10.4 - Array Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4).

> A component of an array is accessed by an array access expression ([§15.13](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)) that consists of an expression whose value is an array reference followed by an indexing expression enclosed by [ and ], as in A[i].
>
> All arrays are 0-origin. An array with length n can be indexed by the integers 0 to n-1.
>
> ```
> class Gauss {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         int[] ia = new int[101];
>         for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++) ia[i] = i;
>         int sum = 0;
>         for (int e : ia) sum += e;
>         System.out.println(sum);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you.
Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: @user1873251 Added relevant JLS.

Comment: I know the concept, but right know I'm having problem understanding why the i is in the array [] .. the i just counts the value is 1 .. and 2.. till the number of the elements typed ..

Comment: Read the paragraph that contains *an array reference followed by an indexing expression enclosed by `[` and `]`* again.

Comment: Ok, I understand it scans and the position is the referenced by i :)

Comment: The position is referenced by `i`. When you say scans... do you mean accesses sequentially by the index `i`? If so, *yes*.

Answer (score 0):

in your code 
    int[] x = new int [scan.nextInt()];

you are defining the size of an array. you are not storing any elements in here.

So define any elements in an array you have to access it's index and store your value in that specific index

```
x[1] = scan.nextInt()
```

can store the values in specific index

Comment: What kind of Exception should that line give?

Comment: the default value of an array for int is 0

Comment: Well, then your description is wrong. It has nothing to do with storing data in that array or not, you're just entering `0` or `1` as the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Try, add values in array then use array for business logic.

```
int[] x = new int [scan.nextInt()];

for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   System.out.print("Type numbers: ");
   x[i] = scan.nextInt();

  if(x[i] > 0)
      countPOZ++;
  else if (x[i] % 5 == 0)
      countP5++;
  else
      countNONE++;
   }
```

But you missing something `int[] x = new int [scan.nextInt()]` as per your code you are not passing only one element and add that element to your array.

I assist pass multiple elements as comma separated list `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` then in your code you can create array list `int x[] = scan.nextInt().split(",")` then use it.